Recording two GPS L bands simultaneously with USRP N310
I have been using a USRP N310 to record GPS L1 RF data into a file, which I later use to test a GNSS software receiver (gnss-sdr).
Now I am interested in testing the receiver in dual-band operation mode - GPS L1 + L5.
Can someone please indicate how I can record the two bands simultaneously?

L1 is at 1.57 GHz, L5 at 1.18 GHz. The N310 only has a single RX LO for both RX channels, so you can't tune to both at the same time.
The receiver bandwidth is also not large enough, so you can't tune to the middle and receive both to then digitally downconvert them.
So, you simply can't record both at the same time with only an N310. It's not possible, physically!
What you can do is buy an external mixer, use one of your N310's TX paths to synthesize an $f_{L1}-f_{L5}$ tone, and use that to upconvert your L5 band to the L1 band, and then receive it (or, downconvert the L1 to L5, whatever is technically advantageous for you).

an extra +1 for mentioning the idea of tuning to the middle and doing upper side / lower side. I wonder if it is possible to tune somewhere in the middle and then digitally under-sample the higher analog IF frequencies? I suspect there is a Nyquist zone 1 low pass filter in front ADC that would prohibit this.

Yes, I'm afraid that's the case: The N310 uses the AD9371 chipset ("Mykonos" is the ADI codename), and that has an (adjustable!) analog LPF with a maximum 3dB bandwidth of 100 MHz. Though that technique is something I quite commonly recommended to users of the Ettus B210 (uses the AD9361, same single-LO dual channel RX, ~ 56-60 MHz input filter) so that they don't had to shuffle two 60 MHz channels across a USB link into their PC: Because the FPGA on these devices has two digital downconversion chains that are independent from each other in frequency (not in decimation), you can set your…

ADC conversion rate to the maximum sampling rate, tune to the center, and let the device offset tune in the FPGA so that both channels end up being baseband, decimate to the actual channel bandwidth (which often is much smaller), and deliver these two streams to the host computer. Here's a dirty little performance secret: Frontend filtering is good, but far from perfect… so if you just needed to observe the frequency of something according to a reference that's better than what you've got in your lab, say in a physics experiment,:

a GSM signal can be picked up, amplify it sufficiently badly to ensure harmonics where you need them, then as they get intermodulated into your ADC band, you can use them for frequency correction. But. Not something you want to write in your lab report.

@MarcusMüller hello, thanks for the great answer +1. Could you please elaborate "dirty little performance secret"? Actually I don't get what you mean at all, also why is it "Not something you want to write in your lab report"?

@Rokai that trick doesn't apply to your solution; all I'm saying is that if you have a signal about whose information content you don't care, you can do bad things and measure its frequency by using multiple effects that you usually do not want to happen to your signal. So, really, nothing that could help you here.
